# How to get logs in a file when using the timeout command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to grab the logs of my below command to a text file like below:

```
timeout 10 glxheads &> test.txt
```

But unfortunately, I am not not getting any logs transferred to the text file by this approach.

Infact any simple command done under timeout doesnt give out the output to a file.

Note: 
The below command works,

```
glxheads &> test.txt
```

Could anyone suggest any ideas to get around this issue?

Thanks !

Comment: Check out the recipes from this thread http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25372/17649 (`unbuffer`, `stdbuf`, etc.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. I called timeout with two commands: one, that fits into the time interval, and another that does not. Both worked as expected: first wrote all the output to log and the second wrote only a part of its output. Are you sure prints output in the first 10 seconds?

Comment: I did the same test as @Asalle and I can confirm that I cannot reproduce the problem. All worked as expected. Which version of `timeout` are you running? on which system? with which shell? try calling it as `\timeout` to be sure you are not calling an alias...

Comment: Also running `glxheads` from Mesa 8.2.0 produces output in both scenarios.

Comment: I am using `glxheads` from `mesa 8.3.0-1` . `timeout` version 8.25 . @DmitriChubarov I am able to fix this issue using the `unbuffer` command

Comment: `glxheads` doesn't write to stderr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the link specified by Dmitri, I was able to resolve this issue by doing the following:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL timeout 10 glxheads &> test.txt
```

or using

```
unbuffer timeout 10 glxheads &> test.txt
```